# Построение минимального остовного дерева

Tags: c#, графы

Есть построенный граф, в котором все вершины заданы экземплярами класса `Vertex`, а грани - `Edge`. `Vertex` имеют координаты `float x` и `float y`, а `Edge` точки `Vertex a` и `Vertex b`, длину `double length`. Попытка написать алгоритм построения минимального остовного дерева из графа Делоне по алгоритму Прима не увенчалась успехом. Получалось подобное: [image: Неудачный граф]

Где белые ребра - ребра моего "древа", а серые в совокупности с белыми - исходный граф. Вот код моего алгоритма:

```
List<Vertex> tmpVertex = points; //вершины графа на входе
List<Edge> tmpEdges = DelanayTree; //ребра графа входе
List<Vertex> selectedVertex = new List<Vertex>(); //вершины, по которым "прошелся" алгоритм
List<Edge> selectedEdges = new List<Edge>(); // окончательный граф (список ребер)
selectedVertex.Add(tmpVertex[0]); ///подготовка (чтобы не вызвать исключение)
tmpVertex.RemoveAt(0);
foreach (Edge e in tmpEdges) //расчет длинны для каждого ребра
{
    e.length = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(e.b.x - e.a.x) * Math.Abs(e.b.x - e.a.x)) + (Math.Abs(e.b.y - e.a.y) * Math.Abs(e.b.y - e.a.y)));
}
while (tmpVertex.Count > 0) //алгоритм будет работать пока есть над чем работать
{
    List<Edge> conectedEdges = new List<Edge>();
    foreach (Vertex v in selectedVertex) //получение ребер, связывающих выбранные точки
    {
          List<Edge> tmpConnEdges = v.getExtisEgdes(tmpEdges);
          foreach (Edge e in tmpConnEdges) conectedEdges.Add(e);
    }
    Edge minEdge = conectedEdges[0]; //чтобы не вызвать исключение
    foreach(Edge e in conectedEdges) //поиск ребра с меньшей длиной
    {
        if (e.length < minEdge.length) minEdge = e;
    }
    selectedEdges.Add(minEdge); //добавление его в финальный граф
    Vertex nonSelectedVertex;
    if (minEdge.a.vertexExtisInList(tmpVertex)) nonSelectedVertex = minEdge.a; //поиск второй (не выбранной) вершины этого ребра
    else nonSelectedVertex = minEdge.b;
    selectedVertex.Add(nonSelectedVertex); //добавление этой точки в финальный граф
    tmpEdges.Remove(minEdge);
    tmpVertex.Remove(nonSelectedVertex);
}
minimalTree = selectedEdges;
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: a.vertexExtisInList(e) проверяет существование ребра a в списке e. v.getExtisEgdes(tmpEdges) возвращает все ребра, соединенные с v в списке tmpEdges.

Comment: Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста Ваш код и приложите к нему описание хотя бы какое-то.

Comment: И тогда возможно вопрос и решится сам ;))

Comment: @hedgehogues , снабдил код комментариями. Что-нибудь прояснилось?

Comment: Так, а ещё, уточните, что есть "графа Делоне"? Правильно ли я понимаю, что вес каждого ребра -- есть длина, которая высчитывается здесь: `Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(e.b.x - e.a.x) * Math.Abs(e.b.x - e.a.x)) + (Math.Abs(e.b.y - e.a.y) * Math.Abs(e.b.y - e.a.y)))`?

Comment: @hedgehogues , да. Вес ребра считается по т. Пифагора

Comment: Что делает эта часть кода? Перебирает рёбра некоторой, рассматриваемой вершины... И что с ними происходит?
`List<Edge> tmpConnEdges = v.getExtisEgdes(tmpEdges); foreach (Edge e in tmpConnEdges) conectedEdges.Add(e);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой алгоритм так и не заработал (возможно из-за того что я его не правильно понял). Вчера нашел другую формулировку этого алгоритма:

1. Инициализируются списки с данными: ребра, не включенные в дерево, вершины, включенные в дерево, и вершины, не включенные в дерево.
2. выбирается случайная начальная вершина, с которой начнется построение минимального остовного дерева.
3. Цикл while будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока все вершины графа не будут включены в дерево

А в цикле уже:

1. Производится поиск ребра с наименьшим весом, один конец которого – это вершина, входящая в дерево, а другой – нет/
2. Вершина, инцидентная найденному ребру, заносится в список использованных и удаляется из списка неиспользованных.
3. Найденное ребро заносится в список ребер, составляющих дерево, и удаляется из списка неиспользованных ребер.

Переписал код под свои цели:

```
    List notUsedE = new List(DelaunayTree); //неиспользованные ребра есть копия ребер исходного графа
    List notUsedV = new List(points); //неиспользованные вершины есть копия вершин исходного графа
    List usedV = new List(); //список вершин по которым "проехался" алгоритм
    notUsedV[0].inUsedSide = true; //отмечаем что вершина используется
    usedV.Add(notUsedV[0]); //заносим её в список использованных
    notUsedV.Remove(usedV[0]); //удаляем из списка неспользованных
    while (notUsedV.Count>0) //пока есть вершины над которыми можно работать
    {
       List doubleSideE = new List(); //создание списка ребер у которых одна вершина используется, а другая нет
       foreach(Edge e in notUsedE) //для каждого неиспользованного ребра
       {
            if ((e.a.inUsedSide && !e.b.inUsedSide) || (e.b.inUsedSide && !e.a.inUsedSide)) doubleSideE.Add(e); //если у него одна вершина исп., а другая нет, то добавляем в список "двуликих"
       }
       Edge minE = doubleSideE[0]; //инициализация переменной для ребра, у которого минимальный вес
       foreach(Edge e in doubleSideE) //для каждого "двуликого" ребра
       {
           if (e.weight < minE.weight) minE = e; //если его вес меньше веса минимального, то делаем его минимальным
       }
       if (!minE.a.inUsedSide) //если вершина a ребра minE не используется
       {
           notUsedV.Remove(minE.a); //то удаляем вершину a из использованных
           minE.a.inUsedSide = true; //и делам её используемой
           usedV.Add(minE.a);
       } else { //а если b не используется
           notUsedV.Remove(minE.b);
           minE.b.inUsedSide = true; //то делаем её используемой
           usedV.Add(minE.b);
       }
       minimalTree.Add(minE); //добавляем минимальное ребро в конечный граф
       notUsedE.Remove(minE); //и удаляем его из неиспользованных, чтобы алгоритм не прошелся по нему еще раз
    }
```